# How to make SQL search case sensitive?

Tags: sql, postgresql

my `WHERE` statement returns everything that starts with an A to H whether it is capital or lowercase. I have tried to use COLLATE Latin1_General_CS_AS, but I get "collation "latin1_general_cs_as" for encoding "UTF8" does not exist". The simplified query is below.

```
SELECT Move
FROM Moves
WHERE Move BETWEEN 'a' AND 'h';
```

Comment: What is the type and collation of `Move`? Can you show us the schema?

Answer (score 2):

It seems the `BETWEEN` clause can't make use of the `collate` option, so you will need to rewrite it to use `>=` and `<=` explicitly

```
SELECT Move
FROM Moves
WHERE Move >= 'a' collate "C"  
  AND move <= 'h' collate "C"
;
```